# On least-squares with positive semidefinite constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Given real symmetric matrix $\mathbf{R} \in \mathbb{S}^{n\times n}$ and matrices $\mathbf{X}_n, \mathbf{X}_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}{\text{minimize}} & \frac12 \left\| \mathbf{X}_n - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}_{n-1} \right\|_{\text F}^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA} \succeq 0 \end{array}$$

Since the positive semidefinite constraint $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA}\succeq0$ is not based on a typical $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ function, it is not possible to take it into a Lagragian directly. Is there any way to solve such optimization problem?

Comment: Instead of keeping the constraint $A-B=0$ and work with $A$ and $B$, why not simply replace $B$ with $A$?

Comment: I thought such form may be more handy since it'll be both linear for $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. :) I am a beginner and may make lots of mistakes, this thought may also be inappropriate.

Comment: Are the entries of $A$ real? Are the matrices $X_{n},X_{n-1}$ rectangular? do they have real entries? do we know any other structures on the input matrices?

Comment: Yes, all matrices mentioned are real. Other info on structure have been added to description.

Comment: This is a Bilinear Matrix Inequality (BMI https://web.mit.edu/braatzgroup/33_A_tutorial_on_linear_and_bilinear_matrix_inequalities.pdf , which is non-convex and may be difficult to solve, especially if the dimension is not small.  You can try BMIBNB under YALMIP, under MATLAB, which may or may not succeed in globally optimizing it. if you can impose (not overly large) finite lower and upper bound constraints on all the elements of $A$, that will make it easier to solve. How large a value of $N do you need?

Comment: If $A$ only appeared linearly in the semidefinite constraint, it would be an LMI (Linaer Matrix Inequality, a.k.a., Linear SDP), which are convex and relatively easy to solve, except when the dimension is very large., and for which good off the shelf solvers, such as Mosel, and the free solvers SeDuMi and SDPT3 exist.

Comment: Is matrix $\bf A$ symmetric? Where does $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA} \succeq 0$ come from?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case.

Comment: No, $\mathbf{A}$ is confined to real matrix but need not to be a symmetric one. As for $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA}\succeq 0$, this is the expression of a correlation matrix and has to be SPD.

Comment: Please do provide a brief derivation of $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA}\succeq0$.  Do note that if $\mathbf{R} - \mathbf{ARA}$ is **not** symmetric, then asking it to be PSD is kind of nonsense.  PSD-ness is for symmetric matrices.